# Nvidia Gpu stuttering playing Stadia on Kubuntu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, gpu, video-streaming

I recently installed a new card in my old pc (Nvidia 710GT) and I have problems while playing Stadia at 720p resolution or 1080p on Chromium (hw acceleration on).

I have no problems at all streaming a 1080p 60 fps video from youtube, the hw acceleration is working.

Btw, when I play to Stadia, I can start the game normally but, after 20 second or more, the gpu goes crazy and I have a lot of stuttering going on the screen before it goes back to notmal. That is unplayable most of the time.

I am using h264 codec with stadia+ extension..
I am using nvidia 440 proprietary driver on kubuntu 19.10.
I tried Nouveau driver.. Nvidia 435.. Right now I can play only with hw acceleration off because of this issue with the gpu.

I haven't this problem while playing other games.

Answer (score 0):

since your videocard is fairly old you have no vp9 hardware decoding, and you must use h264 decoding. older videocards often struggle with decoding this. Youtube 1080p60 is a much lower bitrate than stadia because stadia is trying to be indistinguishable from gaming on a game pc

Comment: Upgrading the graphics card would make a big difference in performance.

Comment: I think that's a problem with this configuration. My old radeon, struggled  with 1080p.. Btw this time I have decent fps (when it decides to work for 20 seconds and be stable). It looks like more like a glitch. My cpu is at nearly 40% and gpu between 40-60%. I have this issue also with 720p! While using stadia without hw acceleration playing just with my core2duo at 720p goes smooth with the cpu at 70-90%. It is obviously unplayable without hw acceleration at 1080p just with my dual core.. But 720p glitched with hw acceleration? That sounds like something else.